# Run configure, make, make install from another directory

Tags: makefile, configure, automake

Having an Ansible problem where I cannot change directories outside of /tmp and I have a folder in temp where I need to run configure, make and make install ***just like*** I was in the folder.

Some questions:

- When I run configure outside the folder, the Makefile appears in my CWD. How do I get around this?
- Is make -C ./directory/ the way to go for making?

Any ideas on how to accomplish these commands just like I was in the folder itself?

Comment: One idea (untested) is to join your commands together with a `cd`, like `cd /tmp && configure`

Comment: This is a good idea. Thanks. Slightly hacky, but it will probably work!

Comment: `pushd directory && ./configure && make && popd` (as a shell line in ansible) is better than using cd. If make was the only issue, `make -C directory` would suffice.

Comment: The pushd/popd solution has issues: not all shells support it, if a command fails then popd is not run.  Safer, more portable, and simpler is to use `()` to run the cd and command in a subshell, like this: `(cd /tmp/foo && ./configure && make && make install)`  Once the subshell exits the cd operation will be undone.